# Scan with elasticsearch_dsl and slicing taking a long time

Tags: python, elasticsearch, elasticsearch-dsl

I have a query that returns a total of about 50-60 million hits from ElasticSearch. I have tried to split the workload into slices using multiprocessing and while it certainly speeds up the overall process in the beginning, the scan eventually slows down before coming to a halt after gathering about 15-20 million hits. The below code works fine for a smaller result set of about 1 million hits, but I cannot get it to finish in a reasonable amount of time for the larger result set.

```
    from elasticsearch import Elasticsearch as ES
    from elasticsearch_dsl import Search
    import multiprocessing as mp
    from multiprocessing import Pool
    from functools import partial

    SLICES = 5

    es = ES(['https://example.com/'],http_auth = 
                   (user,pwd),timeout = 120)



    def dump_slice(query, index, slice_no):    

        s = Search(using=es,index=index).update_from_dict(query)                                        
        s = s.extra(slice={"id": slice_no, "max": SLICES})     
        s = s.params(scroll='30m',preserve_order=True,size=5000)  
        hits = []                  
        for d in s.scan():                                                          

            my_id = {'id':d.meta.id}
            my_index = {'index':d.meta.index}

            hits.append({**my_id,**my_index,**d.to_dict()})


            if (len(hits) % 250000 == 0):
                logging.info(str(len(hits)) + ' records processed by PID ' + 
                              str(mp.current_process().pid))

        return hits

    q = partial(dump_slice, query, index)     

    with Pool(SLICES) as pool:
        hits = pool.map(q, range(SLICES))
```

Comment: What is your elasticsearch cluster specs, like Memory, Heap Size? What is the average size of the documents?

Comment: @leandrojmp I am not sure as i am new to elasticsearch, do you know how to get this information?